# New Mime Type does not work over https?

Tags: https, mime-type

I added a new Mime Type for Tableau files (twbx) as described here (although using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, on premise and didn't set the icon):
https://kerseub.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/add-new-file-type-in-sharepoint/

The settings I used was:
Extension: twbx
MIME Type: application/twbx

Everything worked fine on my dev environment (SP uses http).

For production (SP uses https) I did the same on all WFE servers (and also did iisreset), but I still don't have "Open" button in Internet Explorer.

In web application - General Settings, in both dev and prod, Browser File Handling is set to Strict.

Browser handling on the doc library is set to "Open in Client" in both cases.

Any idea how to have this "Open" button?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't about https.
On prod, MIME type was added in IIS on the web application level, on dev it was on the top IIS level. Moving MIME type to the top fixed the problem.